# setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution

Tags: upgrade, python, pip

I am trying to install pywavelets lib
I gave a command `pip install pywavelets`
It gave me a error
setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution.

Checking with this error I saw some posts saying that use a command `sudo pip install -U setuptools`
when done it shows the following

```
The directory '/home/raady/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is  
not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please
check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip 
with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. You are using pip version 
7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available. 
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' 
command. The directory '/home/raady/.cache/pip/http' or its parent 
directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been 
disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory.
If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-
py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: 
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. 
This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause 
certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see  
https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg
```

In the instruction I saw and I though I have to upgrade so tried with the command `pip install --upgrade pip`
it showed the following error
[image]
How to rectify this
so that I install pywavelet library.

I am trying to install the packages in the link `[install required packages for python](http://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-packages) I couldnt install any of the package.

Where could be the problem ?
how to rectify it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the error what they are, but could manage to make it work.

I have used the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install python-pkg-resources=3.3-1ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
pip install pywavelets
```

and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all make sure you have all the necessary permissions when you install.

E.g.:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

failed because of a `Permission denied`.

To solve this issue run it as `sudo`, as follows:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```